# Markov chain problem: probability of raining at any given day

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I have a very annoying problem. I am just beginning to learn the Markov chains, and I cant figure out how should I solve this problem.

So I have a transition table showing the state transitions of rain and sunny for yesterday and today.

---

----------------------| today sunny | today raining|

yesterday sunny---| 0.9-----------| 0.1----------|

yesterday raining-| 0.5------------| 0.5----------|

---

I do not know anything about the actual state and I should find the probability of raining at any given day (so kind of probability of training after an infinite number of days).

How should I calculate this? (My problem that is not a finite problem and I am not aware of the actual status).

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Hint:  at equilibrium the probabilities must be the same from day to day.  That is, the probability that it is raining on day $10^6$ must be the same as it is for day $10^6+1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x=(x_1,x_2)$ be a steady state, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the probabilities of a sunny and a rainy day, respectively. Then:
$$x_1=x_0M;\\
x_2=x_1M;\\
\vdots\\
x_{n+1}=x_nM \Rightarrow \\
x=xM \Rightarrow \\
\begin{pmatrix}x_1&x_2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x_1&x_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0.9&0.1\\ 0.5&0.5\end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow \\
\begin{cases}0.1x_1-0.5x_2=0 \\ x_1+x_2=1\end{cases} \Rightarrow \\
(x_1,x_2)=(\frac56,\frac16)$$
Hence, the probability of a rainy day is $\frac16$.

Comment: Hi @farruhota! Thank you for your comment.

However three things I do not understand.
1) Why does $x_{n+1} = x_nM  => x=xM$

Comment: 2) Why is $(x_1 x_2) \begin{pmatrix} 0.9 & 0.1 \\ 0.5 & 0.5 \end{pmatrix} = 0.1x_1 - 0.5x_2 = 0 $
What happened to the other equasion? Why is x_2 negative? And why is this equation equlas to zero?

Comment: 3) And finally where does $x_1 + x_2 = 1$ come from?

Comment: 1) Look at lulu's comment. 2) you expand the matrix equation; the 2nd equation is the same as the 1st, 3) therefore it is replaced by $x_1+x_2=1$.

Comment: Hi @farruhota! Thank you for your replies. Sorry for being such a noob but I really want to understand what is behind your solution.
So 1) point makes sense, understood it. But no 2, I still dont understand it. The product of the two matrices is: 0.9x_1 + 0.5x_2 and 0.1x_1 + 0.5x_2...so how why do you say that they are the same? ...and how does **+0.5x_2** become **-0.5x_2**?
Thank you!

Comment: note: $(x_1 \ \ x_2)=(0.9x_1+0.5x_2 \ \ \ 0.1x_1+0.5x_2) \Rightarrow \begin{cases}x_1=0.9x_1+0.5x_2 \\ x_2=0.1x_1+0.5x_2\end{cases} \Rightarrow \\ \begin{cases}0.1x_1-0.5x_2=0 \\ 0.1x_1-0.5x_2=0\end{cases} \Rightarrow \begin{cases}0.1x_1-0.5x_2=0 \\ x_1+x_2=1\end{cases}$.

Comment: Bang! Of course! Sorry again! Thank you so much! Got it now! Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck in your studies.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to MSE! Hint: You have to consider a discrete-time Markov chain with transition matrix
$$P =\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0.9 & 0.1\\0.5 & 0.5\end{array}\right).$$
Given an initial distribution, say $x_0 = (0.5,0.5)$, the state after $n\geq 0$ time steps is $x_n = x_0 P^n$.